# how to run function on formidable form submit with salesforce formidable integration

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, salesforce, formidable

I have a formidable form(elite version) in wordpress which is using the salesforce CRM. When i submit the form with Ajax it gives an error "we are sorry, seems like you already submitted this form".

I want the form to submit entries and then redirect to the thank you page for all the forms except for 1 form which runs the following function.

```
$(document).on( 'frmFormComplete', function( event, form, response ) {
    var formID = $(form).find('input[name="form_id"]').val();
    if(formID == 7){
      $('.calculator-holder .calculator-header .farmplot-layout-popup').removeClass('d-none');
    }
  });
```

When I remove the Salesforce integration all the forms works perfectly. Please help.